# Changing Desktop Wallpaper Periodically

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem setting the desktop wallpaper using the following code. The SystemParametersInfo returns true but it doesn't change the wallpaper. It is the same as before without any changes. But I want the code to change wallpaper periodically from a directory of *.bmp files. Please let me know where I'm making a mistake.

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(UInt32 uiAction, UInt32 uiParam, string pvParam, UInt32 fWinIni);
    static FileInfo[] images;
    static int currentImage;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:/users/Smart-PC/Desktop");
        images = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.bmp", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        currentImage = 0;

        System.Timers.Timer imageChangeTimer = new Timer(5000);
        imageChangeTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(imageChangeTimer_Elapsed);
        imageChangeTimer.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void imageChangeTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        const uint SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 30;
        const int SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
        const int SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;
        bool gk;
        gk = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, images[currentImage++].FullName, SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE | SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
        Console.Write(gk);
        Console.WriteLine(images[currentImage].FullName);
        currentImage = (currentImage >= images.Length) ? 0 : currentImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related to your current problem, but your next problem is this: You'll get `IndexOutOfRangeException` on the line `Console.WriteLine(images[currentImage].FullName);`.

Comment: Yes, I figured this out but I'm not much concerned about this. I added that statement just for a reference.

Comment: Are there any exceptions being thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this and it works for me. By the way, depending on the OS, it only works with Bitmaps, you need to convert to bitmap if you were to try any other formats.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern Int32 SystemParametersInfo(UInt32 uiAction, UInt32 uiParam, String         pvParam, UInt32 fWinIni);
        private static UInt32 SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20;
        private static UInt32 SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x1;
        private static String imageFileName = "c:\\test\\test.bmp";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SetImage(imageFileName);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void SetImage(string filename)
        {
            SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, filename, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works only for .jpg files, doesn't work for .bmp files. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

the value of `SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER` should be `0x14` and not `30`.

also `SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE` and `SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE` should be of `uint` type.

> > ```
> > const uint SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x14;
> > const uint SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
> > const uint SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;
> > ```

Comment: `30` = `1E` is `SPI_SETDOUBLECLKHEIGHT`

Comment: In that case SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x14 it returns false and still the same.

Comment: @codingactive are you testing on XP or Win7 ?

Comment: I'm using this on windows 7

Comment: ..It works fine with .jpg files, I think I'll have to change the format from .bmp to .jpg before changing.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a very similar application and I use these values and it works for me:

```
public void SetWallpaper(String path)
{
    // DLL Import
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int SystemParametersInfo(
        Int32 uAction, 
        Int32 uParam, 
        String lpvParam, 
        Int32 fuWinIni);

    // Consts
    private const Int32 SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20;
    private const Int32 SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
    private const Int32 SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;

    // Changing the background.
    SystemParametersInfo(
        SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 
        0, 
        path, // desktopBackground is the bmp location
        SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
}
```