# get write permission to "windows" directory in c# (i am using Windows 7 Starter edition)

Tags: c#, permissions

get write permission to "/Windows" directory in c#  (i am using Windows 7 Starter edition)
Proteced from "TrustedInstaller".

Comment: Can you please expand on what are you trying to do, and why? So we can answer your question better.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to write to the windows directory?
You would rarely need to edit/add something there.

If you are trying to install something it would be better to put it in the Program Files directory.
Writing the the Windows dir is very risky. The risk of creating a security vulnerability or damaging your system is very high. 
The only reason I can think off the top of my head would be to edit the hosts file. Even that could be a security risk.

I suspect that if you do have a good reason to be writing to Windows directory, you will need to sign your installer with a 'Application Signing Certificate'

For details see: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732597(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732597%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: i want to overwrite Desktop image in Windows directory. i wanna make a program for changing desktop image.

Comment: @ErgunGuler In that case you should be using the api, which windows has exposed, for changing the wall paper. Since it's not as simple as replacing a file in a directory (You need to set stretch, tile etc) See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051245/changing-desktop-wallpaper-periodically And: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSSetDesktopWallpaper-2107409c

Comment: @DarcyThomas: +1 for bringing up the "why", rather than looking for a workaround. Access restrictions are there for a reason and, more often than not, the user can be given the option to approve individual actions.

Answer (score 1):

That directory is secured so that only admin users have write access. So you need to run your code as a user that is an elevated admin user.

Of course, since the Windows directory belongs to the system, you almost certainly should not be writing there.